# How to make Single lined tabitems header in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have made dynamically generated tab items.[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foN9p.png) It displays tab header 5 nos in horizontally then it comes in the next row. I want it in single line.

```
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  MaxWidth="130" MinWidth="130" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                            <CheckBox Margin="10 0 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding isactive,Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="chkbx" />
                        </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl Content="{Binding TabConten}"></UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it inside a ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <TabControl>
       <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  MaxWidth="130" MinWidth="130" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                        <CheckBox Margin="10 0 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding isactive,Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="chkbx" />
                    </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UserControl Content="{Binding TabConten}"></UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```